# Метод video.get APi VK не выдаёт hash в в поле player а ссылку на youtube а не плеер vk.com/video_ext.php?

Tags: vkontakte-api

Метод video.get APi VK не выдаёт hash в в поле player а ссылку на youtube а не плеер vk.com/video_ext.php?

Отдаёт так

[player] => https://www.youtube.com/embed/IJKEhleHhDk?__ref=vk.api

А нужно так

[player] => http://vk.com/video_ext.php?oid=23962687&id=159622161&hash=008045cc2d45fd4d

Вызываю так

```
function api($method, $params = array())
{
    $params['access_token'] = ACCESS_TOKEN;
    $params['v'] = "5.58";

    $url = 'https://api.vk.com/method/' . $method . '?' . http_build_query($params);
    $response = file_get_contents($url);
    return json_decode($response, true);
}

$api = api('video.get', array(
    'videos' => '429393901_456239017',
));

print_r($api);
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Ну, потому что это видео на самом деле из ютуба, наверное?